# Creating instance in multi threaded environment

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, instance

I am using threaded timer which is creating new instance and call a method like below,

```
Timer_tick()
{
   Car C;
   C=new Car();
   C.Start()      ///  this will take time to complete
}
```

My question is, there is another thread coming with next timer tick and perform same operation.
Then the second thread remove the reference from first Car instance & it will call the start method on new Car instance, since first object does not finished his start method (still in progress) but it doesn't have the “C” variable reference anymore.
Will this create any problem to first instance `Start()` method completeness or execution. 
Can it be collected by GC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Car` instance is local to that particular call of the `Timer_tick()` function. Subsequent calls by other threads operate on their own instances of the `Car` object.

However, it doesn't look like you're doing anything with the car after the function exits, it will eventually get garbage collected without having done anything to it besides running the start function. Is that what you intended?

Comment: So even though the instance doesn't have any reference will it complete the “Start()” method (like isolated instance) .Do you see any pros & cons of this implementation

Comment: It will, because the thread that called `Timer_tick()` won't actually leave the `Timer_tick()` function until the start function is finished. There's not really enough information here to tell you any pros and cons, for that, you'd have to provide what you're actually trying to do, and some more code that shows how you're trying to do it.

Comment: If reference C becomes an Instant variable , then is there any difference.

Answer (score 0):

for your sample, no race condition exists, because C is not a global Object. C is local and each thread run his own copy of the method, So each thread runs the Start method separately and after that garbage collection will occur.

Comment: but it use the same reference and first second thread removes the first thread instance reference C, then first thread's Car object become isolated ,so in this scenario will it continue its execution further